# UITabBarController setSelectedViewController: only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting crash in xcode 6  version at this line

```
 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:]
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.'
```

Its working properly in xcode 5. The self.selectedIndex is giving garbage value.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this. The code is originally written in xcode 4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have made custom tab bar then remove the synthesis of the array of view controllers you are passing. That worked for me.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you mean ? I am having the same issue.