# UITabBarController setSelectedViewController only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITableViewController, example NewsfeedController and have synthesis property for set / get.

```
NewsfeedController* vc = [[NewsfeedController alloc] init];
vc.tagId = 10;
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:vc];
```

It shows error:
[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.'

I see in [UITabBarController setSelectedViewController: only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788499/uitabbarcontroller-setselectedviewcontroller-only-a-view-controller-in-the-tab), it says "remove the synthesis of the array of view controllers you are passing".

Can u give the full code how to implement?  What I need is, I want to change to other tab and pass variable, so in the NewsfeedController can use the variables.  If I use [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0] it can change the tab, but how do I pass the variable and trigger refresh / reinit the view?

And if possible, if use setSelectedViewController, can it change to view that is not listed in all tab controller items. (For example in UITab the tabs are: tab1, tab2, tab3.  But I want to change to tab4).

Comment: WHY do you want to reinit any view? That is a **very** clear sign of not well written code - you should not have to reinit / reload a view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the `NewsFeedController` that is already in the tab bar controller, not create a new instance (which is what you're doing with the code you posted). You get that reference from the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property. So, for instance, if the `NewsFeedController` is in the second tab (the one at index 1), you would do this,

```
NewsfeedController* vc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
```

Comment: I think however he is intentionally trying to create a new instance - for whatever reason...

Comment: @rdelmar 1. Then how do u pass the variable to the existing Controller and reload the Controller.  2.  How do u show the Controller that is not listed there?  Ex: the tab only have tab1, tab2, tab3, but u want to show tab4 which is not included in the tabs.  luk2302: not really create new instance, but how to pass n refresh to Controller.  Thx

Comment: @Jef If the controller is not already in one of the tabs, then you need to add it to the viewControllers array to make it one of the tab controllers (unless you don't want it to be in the tab bar controller, in which case, you present it modally). As far as passing variables, once you have the reference like I show in my answer, you set some property intuit controller.

Comment: @rdelmar yes, i dont want to be in the tab bar controller.  Example like open web view in newsfeed link facebook ios app (iphone), when u click link it will show popup with navigation in the header and content for the webview.  What Controller do u use?  About the passing variables, so I just create method and execute to refresh the Controller? Will try it first them will mark ur answer.  Thx!

Comment: @Jef Like I said, modally present the new controller if that's what you want -- you can embed that controller in a navigation controller if you want a navigation bar. If you do that, you present the navigation controller.

Comment: @rdelmar it is ok, I create a method to filter the NewsfeedController (tabIndex 0), and the NewsfeedController is already changed.  But when I click the first tab (NewsfeedController), it still show the "filtered" one.  I want to show "not-filtered" one.  How can I add a trigger / insert some code when user click tab index? (if we can add a code, I can remove the filter, so whenever user click tab index 0, the filter is cleared).  Thanks!

Comment: @Jef I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to see the unfiltered table when you return from another tab, put code in viewDidAppear of NewsfeedController, that clears the filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79921/discussion-between-jef-and-rdelmar).